# pythonプログラムをPoke-Controller Modifiedというツールで使いたい

Tags: python

よそから拾ったpythonプログラムをPoke-Controller Modifiedというツールで使いたいのだが、それができません。

このツールの右の窓には
Start SV金策
interrupt
とスタートしたとたんinterruptと表示され、機能しないのです。

以下はこの時(このコマンドが機能しない時）に起こっているエラーと思われる内容です。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karo\Downloads\Poke-Controller-Modified-master\Poke-Controller-Modified-master\SerialController\Commands\PythonCommandBase.py", line 53, in do_safe
    self.do()
  File "C:\Users\karo\Downloads\Poke-Controller-Modified-master\Poke-Controller-Modified-master\SerialController\Commands\PythonCommands\ImageProcessingOnly\SV_kinsaku.py", line 31, in do
    if (self.isContainTemplate("SV/kinsaku/Y.png", 0.8, crop=[540,650,590,700])
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ImageProcPythonCommand.isContainTemplate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'crop
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに書いてある通り、`crop`というパラメータキーワードはサポートされていない(unexpected=予期しない)と言うことでしょう。しかし[対象ソースの対象箇所](https://github.com/Moi-poke/Poke-Controller-Modified/blob/master/SerialController/Commands/PythonCommandBase.py#L441)を見るとキーワードはあるはずです。あるいは`-Modified`の付いていない[オリジナル?の該当部分](https://github.com/KawaSwitch/Poke-Controller/blob/master/SerialController/Commands/PythonCommandBase.py#L167)の方にはそれが無く、代わりに同様の使われ方らしい`area`というキーワードがあります。何か版数の微妙な違いとか、何かの改造が行われて両方のリポジトリからも変わってしまった(あるいは古い？)可能性とかが考えられます。Poke-Controller-Modifiedを再度ダウンロード・展開して最新のものに更新するか、`crop`を`area`に変えてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ご指摘、ありがとうございます。参考に致します。